# Allocate week values into months in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have to allocate weekly volume into monthly, but for weeks that overlap into months I need to be able to choose how to split the values. For example:

```
           Week of
Value for   6-Jan   13-Jan   20-Jan   27-Jan   3-Feb
Pens           70       70       70     
Pencils                                   70           Divide equal value accross the days  
Dictionaries                              70           Value only for Jan
Maps                                      70           Value only for Feb
```

To calculate the total value that applies for each month, I have 3 different options and when adding the total per month the result will be as follows.

```
Total Value Jan Feb
Pens        210
Pencils      50  20
Dictionaries 70
Maps             70
```

I thought I could do something like the following. Replicate the table and indicate in wich case an item on an overlappling week needs to be accounted for one month or the other (blank will indicate that needs to be proportionally allocated to the number of days).

```
           Week of
Value for   6-Jan   13-Jan   20-Jan   27-Jan   3-Feb
Pens           70       70       70     
Pencils                                   70           Divide equal value accross the days  
Dictionaries                              70           Value only for Jan
Maps                                      70           Value only for Feb
           Week of
Value for   6-Jan   13-Jan   20-Jan   27-Jan   3-Feb
Pens           
Pencils                                                Divide equal value accross the days  
Dictionaries                               J           Value only for Jan
Maps                                       F           Value only for Feb
```

I want to avoid using macros. Would someone know if there is a way to achieve this through formulas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a 'fact table' with all your information well organized, something like:

```
Product Month-Ref Week-Ref  Value
Pens    Jan       20/jan    70
Pens    Jan       27/jan    70
Pens    Jan       03/fev    70
Pencils Jan       03/fev    50
Pencils Feb       03/fev    20
Dict    Jan       03/fev    70
Maps    Feb       03/fev    70
```

And then create two 'pivot tables' to get the data grouped as you need.

I have done it here: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=F147E0DC661FB58F&resid=F147E0DC661FB58F%2114575&app=Excel&wdo=1

Comment: Thanks Michael for the suggestions and the example. I want to avoid to have to split the value, but I like your approcah to organize it as column and them move it to rows with the pivot.